# Show the ideal $\langle x^2+1, 5\rangle$ isn't maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Show the ideal generated by $x^2+1$ and $5$ isn't maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I thought of the following:

An element of $\mathbb{Z}[x] /I$  is 
$f(x) + \langle x^2 +1 , 5 \rangle = ax+b + I$ where $a , b \in \mathbb{Z}_5$.

$((x+2) + I)((x+3) + I) = x^2 + 1 + I = I$, so the factor ring has zero divisors. It's not a field, and so I isn't maximal.

Is this correct? Is there any other ideas?

Comment: You need to further prove that both factors are nonzero in the quotient ring to conclude that it contains a *nonzero* zero-divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2 + 1, 5 \rangle \simeq \Bbb{F}_5[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle
$$
where $\Bbb{F}_5 = \Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$ is the field with $5$ elements. Now note that $x^2 + 1 = (x - 2)(x + 2)$ over $\Bbb{F}_5$, because $(\pm 2)^2 = 4 \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$. Hence
$$
\Bbb{F}_5[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \simeq \Bbb{F}_5[x] / \langle x + 2 \rangle \oplus \Bbb{F}_5[x] / \langle x - 2 \rangle
$$
and this has non-zero zero-divisors, for example $(1,0)(0,1) = (0,0)$.

Comment: Note: this is essentially your argument, but I think I made it clearer. In particular, it is immediate that the quotient has *non-zero* zero-divisors because $\Bbb{F}_5[x] / \langle x \pm 2 \rangle$ is not the zero ring (so $1 \neq 0$).

Comment: I thought of this , but i couldn't find a ring isomorphic to the quotient ring , is there's any tip how i find isomorphic rings in such cases ?

Comment: Usually it helps to take successive quotients whenever the ideal has multiple generators (like I did for the first isomorphism), and you can apply the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) whenever the ideal is a product of coprime ideals (like I did to get the second isomorphism). I'm afraid that there's not much that you can do other than this.

Answer (score 1):

We have the inclusion of ideals
$$
\langle x^2+1,5\rangle \subset \langle x+2,5\rangle\subset \mathbb Z[x].
$$
Indeed, this follows from $x^2+1=(x+2)(x-2)+5$.

Next, observe that $x+2\not\in \langle x^2+1,5\rangle$. Indeed, the only degree $1$ polynomials in the latter ideal are of the form $5(ax+b)$. Hence $\langle x^2+1,5\rangle$ is not maximal.

Comment: 5x+5 is in < x^2+1,5 > . but it's true that x+2 is not .